# What is the best way to get Angular Code into 2SXC

Tags: 2sxc

I have used the tutorial https://azing.org/2sxc/r/9qdbjvl_ but cannot see how I actually get the Angular App I created into the DNN 2SXC app I created. This step seems to be missing from the tutorial.

Search for any blog, article, tutorial on how to complete this last step but found nothing.

N/A

My Angular App runs inside 2SXC App wrapper

Comment: I'd love to help but I need to know what already works and what not. Is your angular code in the app-folder? is the compiled code in the dist-folder? are you just trying to bundle the files, or are you stuck trying to put the app on the page?

Comment: Thanks iJungleboy. I have the Angular 8 app compiled in the dist folder and 2SXC module compiled in DNN. If I am doing a regular DNN module I compile and zip the module and import into DNN. I am not sure how what I need to do to get my dist folder into the 2SXC App.

Answer (score 0):

There are two models of development

1. Everything is in the 2sxc app, incl. source code. In this case, the resulting build will be in `/dist` or `/live/dist` or something. This model is preferred, when redistributing the app should include the source code and where small changes will be made on site where the app is deployed.
2. The app is simply the runtime, and the source is in another repo. In this case, you must build to the apps folder like `.../portals/0/2sxc/my-angular-app/dist`

Then you have a cshtml file which points to the angular js files and has the `<app...` tag